# pandas DataFrame to dict with values as tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` as follows:

```
In [23]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'Initial': ['C','A','M'], 'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'F'], 'Age': [49, 39, 19]})
         df = df[['Initial', 'Sex', 'Age']]
         df

Out[23]:   
  Initial Sex  Age
0       C   M   49
1       A   F   39
2       M   F   19
```

My goal is to create a dict like this:

```
{'C': ('49', 'M'), 'A': ('39', 'F'), 'M': ('19', 'F')}
```

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
In [24]: members = df.set_index('FirstName', drop=True).to_dict('index')
         members

Out[24]: {'C': {'Age': '49', 'Sex': 'M'}, 'A': {'Age': '39', 'Sex': 'F'}, 'M': {'Age': '19', 'Sex': 'F'}}
```

Then I use a `dict` comprehrension to format the values of the keys as tuples instead of dicts:

```
In [24]: members= {x: tuple(y.values()) for x, y in members.items()}
         members

Out[24]: {'C': ('49', 'M'), 'A': ('39', 'F'), 'M': ('19', 'F')}
```

My question is: is there a way to get a `dict` in the format I want from a pandas `DataFrame` without incurring the additional overheard of the `dict` comprehension?

Comment: Do you want the ages to be strings?

Comment: @unutbu Doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.set_index('Initial')[['Age', 'Sex']].T.apply(tuple).to_dict()

{'A': (39, 'F'), 'C': (49, 'M'), 'M': (19, 'F')}
```

Comment: Instead of the transpose (`T`), you could pass `axis=1` to `apply()`.

Comment: @chrisaycock agreed thx.  as a matter of style I chose `T` for brevity.

Comment: Under some versions (more recent?), using `T` creates a dict of dicts a la `{'A': {'Age': 39, 'Sex': 'F'}, ...}`. while `df.set_index('Initial')[['Age', 'Sex']].apply(tuple, axis=1).to_dict()` produces the desired dict of tuple values.

Comment: I found `.apply(tuple, axis=1)` to be significantly faster (~10x) compared to the transpose (`.T`) in my case as well.

Answer (score 7):

If lists instead of tuples are okay, then you could use:

```
In [45]: df.set_index('Initial')[['Age','Sex']].T.to_dict('list')
Out[45]: {'A': [39, 'F'], 'C': [49, 'M'], 'M': [19, 'F']}
```

Comment: I need tuples, but thanks for the answer! I've upvoted it.